# how to add a css class if validation is not done correctly in angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs

i want my textbox border color red on button click if input is not valid by adding css class using js.
also at place of alert i want a message beside of textbox which will show after condition failed or satisfied.

```js
var app=angular.module('NewApp', ['ngRoute']);


app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
 console.log("controller me");
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 $routeProvider
 .when('/about',{
  templateUrl: "about.html"
 })
 .otherwise({
  templateUrl: "new.html"
 });
});


app.controller('sbmitCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location){
 $scope.Submit=function(){
  console.log("btn clicked");
  console.log("$scope.inputEmail"+ $scope.inputEmail);
      
      
      var regemail=/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      var regmob = /^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$/;
      
      console.log("mobno"+regmob.test($scope.inputEmail));
     
      if (regemail.test($scope.inputEmail) || regmob.test($scope.inputEmail)) {
       alert("matched");  
      }
      else {
       alert("not matched")
      }
      
      

};
});
```

```css
.xt-error {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
}

.xt-error:focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px red;
}
```

```html
<!--index.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-app="NewApp">
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/n.js"></script>
<ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Your code snippet is broken.

Comment: Can you please show your view where your buttons are added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input ng-class="xt-error: error;">
<div ng-show="error">{{myErrorMessage}}<div>
```

And set $scope.error =true; when validation error occur.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use JQuery add/remove functions? Like this:

```js
if (regemail.test($scope.inputEmail) || regmob.test($scope.inputEmail)) {
  alert("matched");
  //Select your input  
  $("your-selector").removeClass("error-class");
  $("your-selector").addClass("ok-class");
}
else {
  alert("not matched");
  //Select your input
  $("your-selector").removeClass("ok-class");
  $("your-selector").addClass("error-class");
}
```

**Try this for AngularJS:**

```js
if (regemail.test($scope.inputEmail) || regmob.test($scope.inputEmail)) {
  alert("matched");
  //Select your input  
  var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( 'your-selector' ) );
  myEl.addClass('error-class');
  myEl.addClass('ok-class');
}
else {
  alert("not matched");
  //Select your input  
  var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( 'your-selector' ) );
  myEl.addClass('ok-class');
  myEl.addClass('error-class');
}
```

Comment: thanks but what i have to do if i wish to have same thing using angular js.

Comment: I'd suggest trying the more "Angular" route and make use of the ``ng-class`` directive.

Comment: can i have solution along with view Facundo